# Chrome changes the subdomain I enter to a different, cached one (MAMP localhost)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, apache-http-server, cache, mamp

Has anybody noticed that Chrome sometimes changes a URL you enter to a slightly different one that you've entered before? Going Incognito fixes the problem, but I want to clear the cached URL, or tell Chrome to not change to these anymore.

I set up a new WordPress site using MAMP. I like to add subdomains for new projects, so I added `127.0.0.1 newsite.localhost` to `/etc/hosts` and added a VirtualHost to MAMP's `httpd.conf`, putting `newsite.localhost` below `oldsite.localhost` (where `oldsite` is another project). I navigate to `newsite.localhost` and Chrome changes it to `oldsite.localhost`. I can only reach `newsite` through an Incognito tab

All of the combinations redirect to `oldsite.localhost`

```
http://localhost
localhost
http://newsite.localhost
```

etc..

EDIT: Here is the relevant part of my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.64.2    localhost
127.0.0.1       oldsite.localhost
127.0.0.1       newsite.localhost
```

And MAMP's `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName newsite.localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/jared/work/MAMP-hosts/new-site
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the contents of your `hosts` file. Chrome isn't changing anything, it is following the "rules" you have specified in your hosts file and/or your Apache configuration. You should also try clearing your cookies.

Comment: Okay, added above. But how does this explain why I can navigate to `newsite.localhost` in an Incognito tab but not in a regular tab? I even cleared cookies for all things `localhost`